# Change with taking pointers-to-members as template arguments in C++17

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, language-lawyer, pointer-to-member

I know that C++17 introduced `template< auto >`, but the following example doesn't use it, yet still only compiles in C++17:

```
struct Foo
{
  int bar;
};

template< int Foo::* >
void takePtrToMember() {}

int main()
{
  takePtrToMember< &Foo::bar >(); // This works everywhere

  constexpr auto x = &Foo::bar;

  takePtrToMember< x >(); // This only works in C++17

  return 0;
}
```

Why doesn't it work in C++11? What has changed in C++17 so it's now allowed there?

Comment: "*Why doesn't it work in C++11?*" What error does the compiler give you?

Comment: "error: ‘x’ is not a valid template argument for type ‘int Foo::*’. It must be a pointer-to-member of the form ‘&X::Y’"